# Custom token in scatter

Tags: eosio.token, scatter

After researching on many sites i don't found any way to do this
Is there any way that in scatter(chrome extention) to show balance of custom token?

As shown in the image it shows balance of EOS and JUNGLE token for an account.

Is there any way to show my own token balance let say XYZ 100.000 ?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The chrome extension is deprecated and unsafe. You should move to the desktop application as soon as possible.

In the desktop application, you can simply click on "View Tokens", and it will list all of your tokens.

Comment: I have deployed my own token so can i add it in desktop wallet ?

Comment: I don't know how Scatter works internally, but if it uses the standard RPC calls to figure out what tokens are on your account, then it should show up automatically when you connect your account through Scatter. If you want a logo to appear with it though, you would probably have to talk to the Scatter team on telegram: @Scatter